# i2cdetect -y 1 detects my driver the first time, not the second. Code generates i/o error

Tags: i2c

After having several issues with this grove i2c motor driver I decided to test the `i2cdetect` once again to ensure it is connected to my bus.

I see that it was on 0x0f like expected and, by mistake, I ran the command a second time. To which I saw the device was no longer being detected.

I reset the device, ran `i2cdetect -y 1` again and it would appear under 0x0f. ran i2cdetect -y 1 a fourth time and it would no longer show up.

I also noticed that when I ran my code, if I did not do an `i2cdetect` it made it past the first line where I wrote to the bus 0x0f but failed on the second line. however if I did run `i2cdetect -y 1` it failed on the first line that I wrote to the bus

It appears to be failing after the first read/write from the bus. Is this an issue with the driver board or with my pi?

Note: I connected the device to my GrovePi unit, I also tried connecting it directly to the pi

Comment: Could power be an issue here?

Comment: I did not think about that. 
I have 4 AA batteries connected to the driver. Perhaps the batteries are bad? Ill buy a new pack today

The driver itself when connected to the grove can only go in one way and I would assume it is supplying the correct volts to the driver

I also tried connecting the driver directly to the pi with the same result.

Comment: It's more likely to be an issue with a poor connection.  How are you preventing 5V from being fed into the Pi's SDA/SCL gpios?

Comment: I assumed the GrovePi would prevent 5v from being fed into the Pis SDA/SCL gpio. But that could not be happening.as, now that you mentioned it, i powered the driver by itself with the pi off and saw that the LEDs on the pi lit up. How should I prevent this?

Comment: The I2C bus needs pull-ups to a positive voltage to work.  The Pi has hard wired pull-ups to 3V3 on pins 3 and 5.  You need to make sure that the kit you are using preferably has no I2C pull-ups or at worst any pull-ups are to no more than 3V3.  Higher pull-ups will likely eventually damage the Pi.

Comment: It appears that the GrovePi does not send 5v back to the Pi (according to the staff from dexter ind. the creators of the GrovePi). Could weak batteries be the issue?

Comment: So you have removed jumper J4 which the grove I2C motor driver has to supply 5V to the I2C interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23296/discussion-between-paulbinder-and-joan).